# Existence of a $\mathbb{Q}$-rational point from the existence of an $\mathbb{F}_p$-rational point for all $p$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry

Suppose I have some $f\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ and some $a\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $f(a)\equiv 0 \mod p$ for all primes $p$. Then of course $f(a)=0$. Suppose now I have a scheme $X$ over $\mathbb{Z}$ and for each prime $p$ I have a point $a_p\in X(\mathbb{F}_p)$ all of which define the same topological point $P\in X^{\text{top}}$. Under which conditions can I then conclude the existence of a point $a\in X(\mathbb{Q})$ also defining the same topological point $P$?

Intuitively the answer seems to be yes, but I know that the problem of determining the existence of rational points on some scheme is very difficult. Is thinking about $K$-rational points as "solutions to equations in $K$" even the correct intuition?

Comment: You might want to look up the Hasse principal - this should produce something in the spirit of what you're looking for.

Comment: @Morph Thinking about $K$-rational points as solutions to equations with coefficients in $K$ is the right intuition, because that is precisely what is.  For example, the $K$-rational points of the affine  scheme $X:=$Spec $K[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/(f_1,\ldots,f_r)$ over $K$ is the set of tuples $a=(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ such that $f_1(a) = \ldots  = f_r(a) =0$. This being said, I do not understand what you mean by "define the same topological point $P\in X^{top}$". Could you clarify this a bit? (Every $a_p$ lies in a different fibre of $X\to $ Spec $ \mathbb{Z}$...How can they define the "same point"?)

Comment: @Morph I think I have some idea of what you mean regarding what Ariyan question. As he says, since the reductions mod $p$ are different fibers of $X \to \operatorname{Spec} \mathbb Z$, the $a_p$ are not literally the same point. But what you are getting at is that these points should, in some sense, form a compatible system of germs which you want to glue to a rational section of the fibration, that is to say a map $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb Q \to X$, which is precisely a $\mathbb Q$-rational point.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! In my lecture we defined a $k$-rational point as a morphism $\text{Spec}(k)\rightarrow X$. On a topological level the image of such a morphism is just one point on the underlying topological space of $X$. I know that if I just have ANY solution for $f(x)\equiv 0 \mod p$ for all $p$ then this does not garantuee the existence of a solution to $f(x)=0$. But what if all these solutions "come from the same point $P$"?